# OpenCV Aruco not compiling

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv3.1, aruco

Trying to compile opencv-3.4.1 with opencv_contrib-3.4.1 in Visual Studio 15 and I'm getting the following error.

CMAKE

```
...

--------------------------------------------------------------

Configuring done
Generating done
```

Visual Studio

```
1>------ Build started: Project: ZERO_CHECK, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>Checking Build System

...

50>c:\lib\opencv_3.4.1\opencv-3.4.1\modules\aruco\src\aruco.cpp(296): error C3646: 'CV_OVERRIDE': unknown override specifier
50>c:\lib\opencv_3.4.1\opencv-3.4.1\modules\aruco\src\aruco.cpp(550): error C3646: 'CV_OVERRIDE': unknown override specifier
50>c:\lib\opencv_3.4.1\opencv-3.4.1\modules\aruco\src\aruco.cpp(776): error C3646: 'CV_OVERRIDE': unknown override specifier
50>c:\lib\opencv_3.4.1\opencv-3.4.1\modules\aruco\src\aruco.cpp(949): error C3646: 'CV_OVERRIDE': unknown override specifier
50>c:\lib\opencv_3.4.1\opencv-3.4.1\modules\aruco\src\aruco.cpp(1184): error C3646: 'CV_OVERRIDE': unknown override specifier
51>opencv_stitching_pch.cpp
50>c:\lib\opencv_3.4.1\opencv-3.4.1\modules\aruco\src\charuco.cpp(285): error C3646: 'CV_OVERRIDE': unknown override specifier
50>Done building project "opencv_aruco.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
54>------ Build started: Project: opencv_interactive-calibration, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
```

I get that 'CV_OVERRIDE' doesn't exist. But I'm not sure why.

I can compile OpenCV 3.4.1 successfully on it's own. But not with the contrib. Is it just a version mismatch, or am I missing something.

**Edit**

I have again downloaded 3.4.1, I discover aruco is included in the standard bundle source. But not the preconfigured build.
When trying to build it, I get the same errors.

Nothing on google, please tell me I've missed something basic...

Answer (score 0):

Did you compile `OpenCV 3.4.1` with EXTRA_MODULE_PATH set to `opencv-contrib 3.4.1` using CMake? Because `opencv/aruco` is included in *contrib-module* since 3.0. I'm using `OpenCV 3.3.1` and I could build it successfully.

Or, alternatively, you could download stand alone `aruco 3.0.10` from [source](https://sourceforge.net/projects/aruco/files/?source=navbar) and build from binary.

Comment: I worked out why it wasn't working. I just havn't posted the it because I have to look up what the module was again. Basically the latest version needs to be compiled on Windows 10, without an additional pack installed. That's why older versions compiled on the same system (Win7). I just gave up and used my laptop that has Win10 installed.

Comment: @Bradmage Great! You can write your own answer below and mark this question answered, so that people don't need to bother reading each comment.

Comment: Of course! Just have to dig through my source comments, don't want to post half information :)